# Photo restoration and Halacha

Tags: halacha, women, contemporary-halacha, pictures, shemirat-eynayim

According to Halacha Is it permissible to post a tzniut picture of a women on a restoration page for people to colourise the picture? Does it depend on if the woman consents, doesn’t consent, or is dead? Have poskim commented on a question like this?

Comment: That doesn't seem to make too much sense because you are asking the person colouring the picture to think about the woman while they are colouring it.

Comment: @TheGRAPKE you don't know that's a problem for the colorer

Comment: @DoubleAA That's moot because it's still what you're asking them to do?

Comment: @TheGRA I don't understand your response

Comment: https://www.jewishpress.com/indepth/opinions/is-the-torah-against-womens-pictures/2017/08/16/

Comment: @Kirk I'm not offering that link as dispositive, just as a trove of sources, some of which may be relevant.